# Как сделать так, чтобы на всех вкладках JTabbedPane работал один буфер обмена?

Tags: java, swing

У меня есть проект текстового редактора с классом, который расширяет `JTabbedPane`

```
  package TextEditor;

  import javax.swing.*;

  public class TextEditorTabbedPane extends JTabbedPane {

  public TextEditorTabbedPane (){

}
public TextEditorScroll getScrollPane (JTextPane pane){
    TextEditorScroll scroll = new TextEditorScroll(pane);
    return scroll;
}
public JTextPane getPane(TextEditorScroll scroll){
     JTextPane pane = scroll.getTextPane();
    return pane;
}
}
```

и  классом, который расширяет `JScrollPane`

```
package TextEditor;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.Document;

public class TextEditorScroll extends JScrollPane {

private JTextPane text = new JTextPane();

public TextEditorScroll (JTextPane textPane){
    super (textPane);
    this.text = textPane;

}
public String getText (){

    return text.getText();
};

public JTextPane getTextPane (){

    return text;
}

public Document getStyledDocument (){
    return text.getStyledDocument();
}

}
```

И метод в главном классе, в котором я создаю `Clipboard`

```
public void createClipboard (JTextPane textPane){

    Clipboard buffer = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
    String bufferStr=tabs.getScrollPane(textPane).getText();
    StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(bufferStr);
    buffer.setContents(stringSelection, null);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex){}
}
```

Проблема в том, что этот буфер создается только один раз на одной из вкладок моего текстового редактора, а на других не работает. То есть я копирую текст во вкладке 1, затем перехожу на вторую вкладку и копирую текст оттуда, но в буфере остается текст из первой вкладки.

Как это исправить?